# HTML/PHP - table cell delimited width

Tags: php, html, html-table

I have this table

```
<table name='test'border='1' style='width: 100%'>
    <tr>
        <th valign='top' style='width: 9%'>No.</th>
        <th valign='top' style='width: 9%'>Epitope/Cluster Sequence:</th>
        <th valign='top' style='width: 9%'>Epitope ID:</th>
        <th valign='top' style='width: 9%'>Source Organism</th>
        <th valign='top' style='width: 9%'>Source Protein:</th>
        <th valign='top' style='width: 9%'>MHC Restriction:</th>
        <th valign='top' style='width: 9%'>RF Score:</th>
        <th valign='top' style='width: 9%'>Assay Score:</th>
        <th valign='top' style='width: 9%'>Assay Type:</th>
        <th valign='top' style='width: 9%'>Effector Origin:</th>
        <th valign='top' style='width: 9%'>Reference ID:</th>
    </tr>
```

And I want to add next more rows and keep the same width, the with delimiter works when I test it using only the first row, but it doesn't work when the new rows are added, my code to add the new rows is:

```
function printResultI($array)
{
    $i=0;
    foreach($array as $row) {
        $i=$i+1;
        echo" 
        <tr>
            <td style='width: 9%'>$i</td>
            <td style='width: 9%'>$row[linear_sequence]</td>
            <td style='width: 9%'>$row[E_ID]</td>
            <td style='width: 9%'>$row[ant_source_organism_name]</td>
            <td style='width: 9%'>$row[E_OBJECT_SOURCE_NAME]</td>
            <td style='width: 9%'>$row[mhc_restriction]</td>
            <td style='width: 9%'>$row[RFS]</td>
            <td style='width: 9%'>$row[assay_score]</td>
            <td style='width: 9%'>$row[AS_TYPE]</td>
            <td style='width: 9%'>$row[effector_origin]</td>
            <td style='width: 9%'>$row[unique_reference_id]</td>
        </tr>";
        }

}
```

I think there might be an issue with my quotes inside the echo, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save yourself a LOT of time and typing by setting up a stylesheet to deal with all the style information--width, borders, etc.  You can also simplify your output using the following coding style:

```
function printResultI($array)
{
    # make an array of the pieces of information from $row that you want to get
    $cols = array( 'linear_sequence', 'E_ID', 'ant_source_organism_name',
        'E_OBJECT_SOURCE_NAME', 'mhc_restriction', 'RFS', 'assay_score', 'AS_TYPE',
        'effector_origin', 'unique_reference_id');

    $i=0;
    foreach($array as $row) {
        $i=$i+1;
        echo "<tr><td>$i</td>";
        # now go through the array and get the appropriate data.
        foreach ($cols as $c) {
            echo "<td>" . $row[$c] . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

Regarding stylesheets, it is best to have them in a separate document, but you can embed style information in the `<head>` of an HTML page using the `<style>` tag. Here's a sample with the table styling you're using:

```
<head>
    <title>Document title here!</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    table {
        border: 1px solid #000;  /* solid black border */
        width: 100%;
    }
    th, td {
        width: 9%; /* sets all td and th elements to width 9% */
    }
    th {
        vertical-align: top;
    }
    </style>
</head>
```

Comment: That works great to save time, thank you! But how do I implement the width issue? I appreciate a lot your help

Comment: I added it, but it still generates a big table, not sure what the issue is

Comment: http://pastebin.com/5zVC3NbF That is more less the code, just excluding the mysql connection and some other functions

Comment: Forgot to add the printing function, should be ok now

Comment: I copy/pasted your new html code and also the printResultI function and this is how the output looks like https://www.dropbox.com/s/u0ompucgxla50gd/wide-table.png?dl=0

Comment: But it is still wide :( I am sorry to bother you that much

Comment: OK -- since the table has a lot of long strings (e.g. epitope ID) in it, it is probably better to remove the table cell width restriction. You could make the font size smaller, too. It also looks like some of the strings in the table are joined with commas, but without spaces between the comma and the next word... is that coming from the database?

Comment: Updated to make the font a little smaller and add spaces after the commas: [try this one](http://pastebin.com/sPTL3SeL).

Comment: No, the commas are added by me, do you think that might be the issue? To join them using ", " instead of ","?

Comment: Yes -- if there is no space, the browser thinks it is all one word, and browsers don't like to make a break in the middle of a word unless they really have to. I put in a fix that adds spaces after the commas -- see how that looks.

Comment: Than you! I appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
<td style='width: 9%'>".$row[linear_sequence]."</td>
```

Comment: Ok, I tried usign the ".$variable[]." but it still produces the longer table